# How to write a select statement inside another select in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this query?
it gives a syntax error near the 2nd select

```
SELECT b.mc_boxes_idmc_boxes,
          t.idtitles, 
          t.title,
          t.languages_idlanguages,
          MAX(h.idtitle_history),
          MAX(h.edition)
          (SELECT h.preview, h.file WHERE h.idtitle_history = MAX(h.idtitle_history))
                        FROM mc_boxes_has_titles b
                        LEFT JOIN titles t ON b.titles_idtitles = t.idtitles
                        LEFT JOIN title_history h ON h.titles_idtitles = t.idtitles
                        WHERE b.mc_boxes_idmc_boxes = 12
                        AND h.edition IS NOT NULL
                        GROUP BY b.mc_boxes_idmc_boxes, idtitles
                        ORDER BY b.sortorder;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

looks like you are missing a comma after `MAX(h.edition)`

```
SELECT b.mc_boxes_idmc_boxes,
          t.idtitles, 
          t.title,
          t.languages_idlanguages,
          MAX(h.idtitle_history),
          MAX(h.edition), 
          (SELECT h.preview, h.file WHERE h.idtitle_history = MAX(h.idtitle_history))
FROM mc_boxes_has_titles b
LEFT JOIN titles t ON b.titles_idtitles = t.idtitles
LEFT JOIN title_history h ON h.titles_idtitles = t.idtitles
WHERE b.mc_boxes_idmc_boxes = 12
     AND h.edition IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY b.mc_boxes_idmc_boxes, idtitles
ORDER BY b.sortorder;
```

besides the comma, you are selecting two fields in your subquery

```
SELECT b.mc_boxes_idmc_boxes,
          t.idtitles, 
          t.title,
          t.languages_idlanguages,
          MAX(h.idtitle_history),
          MAX(h.edition), 
          (SELECT preview FROM title_history WHERE idtitle_history = MAX(h.idtitle_history)),
          (SELECT [file] FROM title_history WHERE idtitle_history = MAX(h.idtitle_history))
FROM mc_boxes_has_titles b
LEFT JOIN titles t ON b.titles_idtitles = t.idtitles
LEFT JOIN title_history h ON h.titles_idtitles = t.idtitles
WHERE b.mc_boxes_idmc_boxes = 12
     AND h.edition IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY b.mc_boxes_idmc_boxes, idtitles
ORDER BY b.sortorder;
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE h.idtitle_history = MAX(h.idtitle_history)), (SELECT h.file WHER' at line 7

Comment: I made a slight change to the subquery above to include a FROM yourtable.

Comment: Actually i want to get the preview and file columns according to idtitle_history. if idtitle_history is 219 it should give preview and file for that id which it is not giving with single select

Comment: AHHHH... it worked but i removed the brackets from file... Thanks a lot for ur help :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to bluefeet's answer, you may want to check for reserved words. "File" for example is a reserved word in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Alias it as a virtual table. Change something like

```
SELECT b.mc_boxes_idmc_boxes,
          t.idtitles, 
          t.title,
          t.languages_idlanguages,
          MAX(h.idtitle_history),
          MAX(h.edition)
          (SELECT h.preview, h.file WHERE h.idtitle_history = MAX(h.idtitle_history))
                        FROM mc_boxes_has_titles b
                        LEFT JOIN titles t ON b.titles_idtitles = t.idtitles
                        LEFT JOIN title_history h ON h.titles_idtitles = t.idtitles
                        WHERE b.mc_boxes_idmc_boxes = 12
                        AND h.edition IS NOT NULL
                        GROUP BY b.mc_boxes_idmc_boxes, idtitles
                        ORDER BY b.sortorder) as virtual_column_alias;
```

Check this out. Hope this will work.